# How to fetch song from a specific folder?

Tags: android

This code read all folder in storage to get song. Is it possible to read from a specific folder instead of all ?

```
private ArrayList<File> findMusicFiles (File file){
        ArrayList<File> musicfile = new ArrayList<>();
        File [] files = file.listFiles();

        for(File currentFiles: files){
            if(currentFiles.isDirectory() && !currentFiles.isHidden()){
                musicfile.addAll(findMusicFiles(currentFiles));
            } else  {
                if(currentFiles.getName().endsWith(".mp3")){
                    musicfile.add(currentFiles);
                }
            }
        }
        return  musicfile;
    }
```

Comment: This function receives a File as a parameter. Just call if the first time with the desired File path you need, it won't scan the whole phone.

Comment: @DanBaruch How do you do that? Do I put it in the currentFiles.isDirectory or somewhere else ? I'm new to this so I don't really get it.

Comment: File f = new File(*Path to your desired directory*); and then you simply call findMusicFiles(f)

Comment: Like this ?
`if(currentFiles.isDirectory() && !currentFiles.isHidden()){
                File f = new File("Download");
                musicfile.addAll(findMusicFiles(f));`

Comment: No. What you posted is a function. You don't change it. You call it the way you wrote, just with out the if at the top. File f =... and then MyFileList.addAll(findMusicFiles(f))